# Wordpress Shortcode to query a custom field?

Tags: database, wordpress

I'm new to shortcode creation (I have a basic one I wrote to place graphic stars within pages for our movie reviews) and had an idea on something to do next that I need some input on.

As mentioned, we do reviews and provide stars for the movies that are in a custom field we added. The problem is that we have each rating shown in 3 places -- the review, a sidebar for most current reviews and a page for the compendium of all reviews for the current year. The issue is that each are manual so we're introducing bad data every so often. For example a movie may rate 5 stars but a slip on the keys and it's a 4 in the compendium.

So I'd like to change our "stars" shortcode from simply displaying graphical stars to instead pass it the URL for the review and have it use that to find the record in the database and pull the rating from it. The URL for the review is in the sidebar and the compendium so it's already part of the process.

How would I go about doing that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function retrieves data from a custom field. For example, if your custom field is called `stars` and contains an integer from 0 to 5, then you can use the following code to insert a star rating by placing a `[star-rating]` shortcode into your post:

```
function insert_star_rating() {
  $ratings = array('☆☆☆☆☆','★☆☆☆☆','★★☆☆☆','★★★☆☆','★★★★☆','★★★★★');
  $score = intval(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'stars',true));
  return '<span class="star-rating">'.$ratings[$score].'</span>';
}
add_shortcode('star-rating', 'insert_star_rating');
```

Obviously you need to add code to handle missing ratings and ratings that are outside the range from 0 to 5, but that shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: Thanks. That helps but in a different area than what I hoped for. So, the ratings are numeric from 0 to 5 so that's not a problem. The issue I have is understanding how to look up a review by its URL and return the rating for that review. In the case of the compendium, it's a page that has over 100 reviews listed on it so get_post_meta won't work. Nor will that work for the sidebar widget.

Comment: Then the title of your question is wrong. If you want help accessing custom fields from URLs (not post IDs?) and from inside unnamed widgets, you're going to have to explain what you've tried so far and why it isn't working.

Comment: Wordpress has a post_ID you can get. The problem is, in the sidebar and the Compendium page, it's not a post but a listing of a slew of posts. Thus I can't simply just get the ones desired as they're very hard to filter. For example, the sidebar contains not only the links to latest reviews but also links for popular films that might not be so recent (theaters often hold films for some time). The Compendium is all movies we covered "this year" but "this year" isn't January 1. It's when we see a film for 2013 which is on some random day in January (studios have an odd way of determining year).